# Unable to trigger workflow

Tags: development, workflow, client-object-model, asmx

A sharepoint info path form calls this ASMX web service. The webservice inserts items into a sharepoint list like so...

```
                                    item["Area"] = Area;
                                    item["Problem"] = Problem;
                                    item["Notes"] = notes;                                      
                                    item.Update();
                                    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The record gets inserted into the list but the workflow is unable to trigger. What's weird is that if I try running the same code locally on my machine, I can insert into the list and trigger the workflow.

However, when running the asmx on the sharepoint front end web server, it can insert into the list but will not trigger the work flow. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is it inserting the information using a system account? If so, the workflow will not trigger.

Comment: Oh I believe so. How would you recommend to get around this?

Comment: Not use a system account to post the data to the web service, use a service account that isn't the system account or use the current users credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments for your question. If you call the web service using system account your service updates data also as system account. SharePoint workflows doesn't work correctly with system account. You need to use another account to call you service.

Comment: Would I be able to call it programatically?

Comment: In most cases SharePoint code runs under user who is logged in if you didn't impersonate it. So, if you use not system account to call service, your workflow should be triggered.